# How do you change the font of an equation in PowerPoint 2010?

Tags: math, fonts, editor, powerpoint

In PowerPoint 2010, how do you change the font of an equation from the default of Cambria Math to, for instance, Times or Arial?

Comment: +1. This question is general enough that it helped to solve my problem - changing the font of an equation. Yes, I should have tried just changing the font first, but after trying stretching the equation box, I didn't even think of that.

Comment: Another +1. Changing the font in the regular, expected way does absolutely nothing. This should be re-opened.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Select the equation, then on the Design tab, Tools group, choose Normal text.

[image: Visualization of the guidance]

You can then select the contents of the equation and choose another font.
Not all of the text will change; some probably have to remain as-is because not all fonts contain all of the needed symbols.